# ABAP: pass some variables, but the program is giving error - why?

Tags: abap

```
**********the data that i am using************

DATA: BEGIN OF morada,

    gpart         LIKE fkkvkp-gpart,
    vkont         LIKE fkkvkp-vkont,
    vertrag       LIKE ever-vertrag,
    name1         TYPE c LENGTH 100,
    full_address  TYPE c LENGTH 255,
    address_1_1   TYPE c LENGTH 60,
    address_1_2   TYPE c LENGTH 60,
    address_1_3   TYPE c LENGTH 60,
    postal_code_1 TYPE c LENGTH 60,
    local_1       TYPE c LENGTH 60.

DATA END OF morada.

DATA: BEGIN OF istab,                                       "OCCURS 0,

*aninhamos as tabelas.

        color(4) TYPE c,
        gpart    TYPE fkkvkp-gpart,
        vkont    TYPE fkkvkp-vkont,
        vertrag  TYPE ever-vertrag,
        vkonto   TYPE ever-vkonto.

DATA END OF istab.

DATA:  itab     LIKE TABLE OF istab  WITH HEADER LINE,

      p_istab  LIKE TABLE OF istab  WITH HEADER LINE,

      p_morada LIKE TABLE OF morada WITH HEADER LINE.
```

then in other include.

```
PERFORM map_data 
USING itab
CHANGING p_morada.

FORM map_data  USING    pt_istab  TYPE itab
               CHANGING pt_morada TYPE morada.

Endform
```

in form, he will not going to recognize the 'type itab' neither 'type morada'... why

Comment: Please post a minimal working example (MWE), not some unrecognizable fragments of code - this will increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: in whixh sequence do you load the includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would vote up vwegert answer but do not have the reputation to do so.

Type code below, along with data and form changes necessary to use the types. You're naming conventions could also use some work but i will leave that to you!

```
 TYPES: BEGIN OF morada,
  gpart         LIKE fkkvkp-gpart,
  vkont         LIKE fkkvkp-vkont,
  vertrag       LIKE ever-vertrag,
  name1         TYPE c LENGTH 100,
  full_address  TYPE c LENGTH 255,
  address_1_1   TYPE c LENGTH 60,
  address_1_2   TYPE c LENGTH 60,
  address_1_3   TYPE c LENGTH 60,
  postal_code_1 TYPE c LENGTH 60,
  local_1       TYPE c LENGTH 60,
  END OF morada.

 TYPES: BEGIN OF istab,
      color(4) TYPE c,
      gpart    TYPE fkkvkp-gpart,
      vkont    TYPE fkkvkp-vkont,
      vertrag  TYPE ever-vertrag,
      vkonto   TYPE ever-vkonto,
  END OF istab.

 DATA:  itab TYPE TABLE OF istab,

   p_istab  TYPE TABLE OF istab,

   p_morada TYPE TABLE OF morada.


PERFORM map_data
USING itab
CHANGING p_morada.


 FORM map_data  USING    pt_itab
            CHANGING pt_morada.

 ENDFORM .
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `DATA` statement to declare **variables** named `itab` and `morada`. Then you try to use the `USING … TYPE …` addition to refer to **data types** of the same name. This won’t work. Try looking up the keyword documentation for `TYPE` and use that instead of `DATA`.